# CakePHP 3 - Assocation BelongsToMany and hasMany - limit columns by select

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

Good day!
I have small problem with CakePHP 3. I have association like that:

```
       $this->belongsToMany('AdminUserGroup',[
        'classname' => 'AdminUserGroup',
        'foreignKey' => 'admin_user_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'group_id',
        'joinTable' => 'AdminUsersGroups'
    ]);
```

I am returning records with this code:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $ble = $this->find()
        ->contain(['AdminUserGroup' ]);
        return $ble;
}
```

Until that it works, but when i want to select specified fields i have problem. When I add select method i don't see columns from contained table:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $ble = $this->find()->select(['id', 'name', 'surname'])
        ->contain(['AdminUserGroup']);
        return $ble;
}
```

So I added callback query:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $ble = $this->find()->select(['id, name, surname'])
        ->contain(['AdminUserGroup' => function ($q) { return $q->select(['group_name']);}]);
        return $ble;
}
```

But it still dont work. I can see only fields from main table. Fields with contained table doesn't appear.

```
{
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Ola",
    "lastname": "BleBle",
    "admin_user_group": []
},
```

Haw can I repair it?

Comment: How looks your SQL query? Hint: ```->select(['id, name, surname'])``` would be ```->select(['id', 'name', 'surname'])```

Comment: Don't look at that. It is small mistake, because i write that code from my mind, it was works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain) includes the following comments:

> When you limit the fields that are fetched from an association, you must ensure that the foreign key columns are selected. Failing to select foreign key fields will cause associated data to not be present in the final result.

and

> If you have limited the fields you are loading with select() but also want to load fields off of contained associations, you can pass the association object to select().

and

> Alternatively, if you have multiple associations, you can use autoFields().

And there are helpful examples there. So:

```
$ble = $this->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'surname'])
    ->contain(['AdminUserGroup' ])
    ->autoFields(true);
```

or if you're using 3.1 or higher:

```
$ble = $this->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'surname'])
    ->select($this->AdminUserGroup);
```

From the example, it looks like the `contain` call may not be required in the second version, so I've left it out.

Comment: Thank you my Master, my Lord! You save my life. I almost was fired, my boss Mr Karolak and supervisor Miss Hot17 almost killed me, because I was bad programmer. From this day I will be good programmer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
`$ble = $this->find()->select(['Table.id, Table.name, Table.surname'])->contain(['AdminUserGroup']);`

Comment: No, its still dont works, i have same result like before :(

Comment: So are you expecting data in ```"admin_user_group": []```?

Comment: Yes, data from "group_name" field. When I dont use SELECT method, i see that data

Comment: Then you are looking for this : $ble = $this->find()->select(['id, name, surname', 'AdminUserGroup.fieldName'])->contain(['AdminUserGroup']);

Comment: That does not work too. I have syntax error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AdminUserGroup.group_name' in 'field list'. Column and table names are entered correctly

Comment: Does group_name exist in table admin_users_groups table?

Comment: Yes, it exists. All column names are valid, i checked it twice... tfu! four times

Comment: Modify your associations like this and then try : `$this->belongsToMany('Groups',[
        'foreignKey' => 'admin_user_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'group_id',
        'joinTable' => 'admin_users_groups'
    ]);`

Comment: Nope, that does not change anything

Comment: Then don't know what you are doing wrong because I tried myself and working fine for me.

Comment: Do you use belongsToMany association? And it works? If I use hasOne or belongsTo it works. But if I use belongsToMany or hasMany, it is not work

Comment: Yes! there must be something that you are missing. I think the group_name is in the groups table?

Comment: But listen - when I don't use any filters (like SELECT) it works perfectly. Problem starts when I use SELECT method.

Comment: This is working fine for me after the changes in the relationship what I suggested : ```$ble = $this->find()->select(['id', 'name', 'surname'])->contain(['Groups']);```